# Magento indexer doesn't index Product categories and Catalog product rule indexes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

There is no error. Magento indexer doesn't index Product categories and Catalog product rule indexes. I have tried both update on schedule and update on save. Any clues please?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogrule_product
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Only word. Amazing.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: One more help. Magento 2.3 account create link is broken and I get 404 page not found. This happens intermittently. The link is restored and works fine upon cache clean and flush. Any clues please?

Comment: Check the network or for console errors, check your files permissions , restart nginx , check the cookie domain.

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run these commands respectively:**
php bin/magento indexer:reset 
or
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category

php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogrule_product
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

```
[2022-08-02 10:51:06] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /home/ubuntu/sites/public_html_2019/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/GroupRepository.php:70)"} []
[2022-08-02 10:51:06] main.CRITICAL: Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log. at /home/ubuntu/sites/public_html_2019/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Indexer/IndexBuilder.php:257)"} []
issue not solved
```